# How to remove a row of data from a ImportHTML

Tags: google-sheets, espn

I have a project for school, to make a Fantasy League in Google Sheets. I am trying to grab the game-by-game states for the players I have on my team. I only have one problem:

how do I remove the REGULAR SEASON STATS without affecting next week's results?

Example: [Player](http://www.espn.com/nfl/player/gamelog/_/id/14880/kirk-cousins).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your ImportHTML in a [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) that selects `where Col1 <> 'REGULAR SEASON STATS'`.

Comment: That does remove REGULAR SEASON Stats, but I want the whole row to be removed, Not just that text.  Thanks, For Your Quick Response.